# Parallel processing in HDFS command execution

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2, file-copying

If I were to copy a directory (with 10 files in it) from local to HDFS,

would it be better to write a single

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal <dir_loc> <hdfs_loc>
```

or

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal <File1> <hdfs_loc>
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal <File2> <hdfs_loc>
..
```

> The commands given above will be in multiprocessing code, hence not sequential.

My question is will it help improve speeds if I run commands in parallel? Or will it both be the same as it runs on the same cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Your second code snippet will not actually run them in parallel; that would be sequential (the command is synchronous). If you actually want to run the uploads in parallel you should instead write:

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal <File1> <hdfs_loc> &
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal <File2> <hdfs_loc> &
...
```

Whether or not this will speed things up is very dependent on your hardware and configuration. Let's assume you are using the default replication factor (3), and that the machine you are running the upload from is identical to the machines you run your DataNode processes on (has the same available network bandwidth). When you upload a file to a DataNode, it then streams the data to other DataNodes to achieve the desired replication factor. Thus, if uploading a single file at a time, the DN's network should saturate before your uploading machine (it has to both receive the data and transmit it along). Doing multiple uploads in parallel will result in the transfer going to different DataNodes, so you may be able to use more available bandwidth. Doing more than a small number in parallel will likely saturate the uploading machine's network bandwidth and result in diminishing returns.

If, however, you did the uploads from multiple machines, then you could greatly speed up the process, as each uploading machine could be sending to a different DataNode on the cluster.

TL;DR It may help a bit but only to a certain extent; you will be limited by the capabilities of the uploading machine.

Comment: Will be using `multiprocessing` to run the commands in parallel (hence not sequential).